# Mathematical expression of SCAN (Strongly Constrained and Appropriately Normed) constraints in DFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-functional-theory

**Moved to [materials stackexchange](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/mathematical-expression-of-scan-strongly-constrained-and-appropriately-normed).**

I'm compiling the mathematical expression of [SCAN](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.036402) (Strongly Constrained and Appropriately Normed) functionals' constraints, but apparently they are not very obvious from their paper (at least for me).
I have compiled some constraints from the [SCAN paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.036402), the [PBE paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865), and [Perdew's presentation](http://mcc.illinois.edu/workshops/electronicstructure/2017/talks/ES_2017_Perdew.pdf), but some are missing.
So if you could help me completing the list below (or checking or just giving directions), it would be greatly appreciated.

**General form**

$$
\begin{align}
E_{xc}[n] &= \int n \varepsilon_x^{unif}(n) F_{xc}(s,\alpha)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \\
E_x[n] &= \int n \varepsilon_x^{unif}(n) F_x(s,\alpha)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \\
E_c[n] &= \int n \varepsilon_x^{unif}(n) F_c(r_s,t,\zeta,\alpha)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = \int n\left[\varepsilon_c^{unif} + H(r_s,t,\zeta,\alpha)\right]\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \\
\end{align}
$$
where $\varepsilon_x^{unif}(n) = -(3/4\pi)(3\pi^2n)^{1/3}$ and $\varepsilon_c^{unif}$ are obtained from [Perdew & Wang, 1992](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.45.13244) and the variables $s,\alpha, r_s,t,\zeta$ are listed in SCAN's paper [supplementary material](https://journals.aps.org/prl/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.036402/SCAN_Sup.pdf).

**Exchange constraints**

1. Negativity
   $$
   F_x(s,\alpha) > 0
   $$
2. Spin-scaling
   $$
   E_x[n_{\uparrow}, n_{\downarrow}] = \frac{1}{2}\left(E_x[2n_{\uparrow}] + E_x[2n_{\downarrow}]\right)
   $$
3. Uniform density scaling
   $$
   E_x[n_\gamma] = \gamma E_x[n]\mathrm{, where}\ n_\gamma(\mathbf{r}) = \gamma^3 n(\gamma \mathbf{r})
   $$
4. Fourth order gradient expansion (the expression is from [Perdew's presentation](http://mcc.illinois.edu/workshops/electronicstructure/2017/talks/ES_2017_Perdew.pdf))
   $$
   \lim_{s\rightarrow 0, \alpha\rightarrow 1} F_x(s,\alpha) =  1 + \frac{10}{81}s^2 - \frac{1606}{18225} s^4 + \frac{511}{13500} s^2(1-\alpha) + \frac{5913}{405000}(1-\alpha)^2
   $$
5. Non-uniform density scaling
   $$
   \lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}F_x(s,\alpha) \propto s^{-1/2}
   $$
6. Tight lower bound for two electron densities
   $$
   F_x(s,\alpha=0) \leq 1.174
   $$

**Correlation constraints**

7. Non-positivity
   $$
   F_c(r_s,t,\zeta,\alpha) \geq 0
   $$
8. Second order gradient expansion
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}H(r_s, \zeta, t, \alpha) &= \beta \phi^3  t^2 \\
   \beta &\approx 0.066725
   \end{align}
   $$
9. Rapidly varying limit (using the term from PBE's paper, instead of from SCAN's paper, is it "*Uniform density scaling to the low density limit*"?)
   $$
   \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}H(r_s, \zeta, t, \alpha) = -\varepsilon_c^{unif}
   $$
10. Uniform density scaling to the high density limit
    $$
    \begin{align}
        \lim_{r_s\rightarrow 0}H(r_s, \zeta, t, \alpha) &= \gamma \phi^3\ln \left(t^2\right) \\
        \gamma &= \frac{1}{\pi} (1 - \ln 2)
    \end{align}
    $$
11. Zero correlation energy for one electron densities
    $$
    H(r_s, \zeta=1, t, \alpha=0) = -\varepsilon_c^{unif}
    $$
12. Finite non-uniform scaling limit (**I don't know this**)

**Exchange and correlation constraints**

13. Size extensivity (**I don't know this**)
14. General Lieb-Oxford bound
    $$
    F_{xc}(r_s, \zeta, t, \alpha) \leq 2.215
    $$
15. Weak dependence upon relative spin polarization in  the low-density limit (**I don't know this**)
16. Static linear  response of the uniform electron gas (**I don't know this**)
17. Lieb-Oxford bound for two-electron densities
    $$
    F_{xc}(r_s, \zeta=0, t, \alpha=0) \leq 1.67
    $$

Comment: You may be able to find help in the new Materials Modelling Stack: https://materials.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, did it here: https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/1322/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.